# Multiplicate values between objects by the index

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm stuck, I have two objects

**Object 1**

```
29: {value: 29, price: "145"}
30: {value: 30, price: "160"}
```

**Object 2**

```
29: {value: 29, count: 2}
30: {value: 30, count: 3}
```

I'm trying to multiplicate the price by the count in the same index, i tried with Object.assing to copy the value of the Object 1 to the Object 2, and then multiplicate the values in the same Object, but i don't have lucky

I'm trying to keep only one element that contains the sum of both elements

Comment: Can you share the code you've tried or used? This will help me and others answer your question more easily

Comment: please add your expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem, i store the object inside an array and then i did a map on it, then i did a Reduce() that return a unique value of the arrays.

```
  let object1 = [
  {value: 29, price: 145},
  {value: 30, price: 160}
  ]

  let object2 = [
  {value: 29, count: 2},
  {value: 30, count: 3}
  ]

  var objResult1 = []

  {object1.map(price => {
      objResult1.push(price.price);
  })}

  var objResult2 = []

  {object2.map(count => {
    objResult2.push(count.count);
  })}

  var final = (objResult1.reduce(function(r,a,i){return r+a*objResult2[i]},0));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's a better (*more declarative*) way to do this, but off the top of my head this is what I came up with.
(PS. The names `object1` and `object2` are a bit misleading, these are both arrays of objects)

```
function getTotals(object1, object2) {
    let finalObject = []
    for (let i = 0; i < object1.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < object2.length; j++) {
            if (object1[i].value == object2[j].value) {
                const value = object1[i].value;
                const total = object1[i].price * object2[j].count;

                finalObject.push({ value, total });
            }
        }
    }

    return finalObject;
}
```

The result with your input will be...

```
let object1 = [
    {value: 29, price: 145},
    {value: 30, price: 160}
]

let object2 = [
    {value: 29, count: 2},
    {value: 30, count: 3}
]

console.log(getTotals(object1, object2));
// Will return
// [{ value: 29, total: 290 }, { value: 30, total: 480 }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the math of `x * 1 = x`:

```js
const prices = [{value: 29, price: 145}, {value: 30, price: 160}] 
const counts = [{value: 29, count: 2}, {value: 30, count: 3}]

const totalsObj = [...prices, ...counts].reduce(
  (acc, {value: k, price = 1, count = 1}) => ({
    ...acc, [k]: acc[k] || 1 * price * count
  }), {}
)

const totalsArr = Object.entries(totalsObj).map(
  ([k, v]) => ({ value: k, total: v})
)

console.log(totalsObj)
console.log(totalsArr)
```